# Best way to accept a generic method argument Java

Tags: java, generics

I need a method to accept a parameter that can be either String or int. I then need to check if its String or int and perform some action accordingly.

What is the best way yo achieve this in Java? Should the argument accept a T param or an Object param? Either way i guess I have to perform an instanceof to get the actual type?

Comment: You should read something for Java generic, you try to use primitive type in your example not objects. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Answer (score 2):

Use overloading *if* the type is known at compile time:

```
public void doStuff(String s) {
    // ...
}

public void doStuff(int i) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And if you want to get freaky, use the Visitor pattern.